# how to wait a script run inside gnome-terminal to be finished before executing next line?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, subprocess, os.system

i have a bash script with name script.sh

```
for i in $(seq 0 10 100) ; do sleep 1; echo $i | dialog --gauge "Please wait" 10 70 0; done
```

and i have python code to call that script

```
import os
cmd = './script.sh'
os.popen("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \""+cmd+";exit\"'").read()
print("Finished")
```

that code open new terminal to execute that script and then run print code without wait until terminal i exit.

now, i want to execute that print code after the terminal is exit.

Comment: `gnome-terminal` spawns a background process to run the terminal. Also, the output doesn't go to its standard output, it's displayed in the terminal window, so you can't use `read()` to get the output.

Comment: BTW, using string concatenation to form shell commands is a _very_ bad idea -- it lends itself to shell injection vulnerabilities. Nothing wrong with it as long as `cmd = './script.sh'`, but what's the point of storing `cmd` in a separate variable if it can't be replaced with more complex values?

Comment: ...but yes, this isn't really a python question or a bash question, it's a gnome-terminal question specifically. Neither python itself or bash itself is a source of your problem.

Comment: Also, `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c ./script.sh'` is silly: It starts _two_ shell interpreters instead of one. You should just write `gnome-terminal -e ./script.sh`; if that doesn't work it means either your script's permissions are wrong (needs a `chmod +x`) or it doesn't have a shebang (a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` line or similar). For similar reasons, it's best not to give scripts, especially _bash_ scripts (which are not `sh` scripts) a `.sh` extension.

Comment: BTW, the `-e` argument to gnome-terminal is deprecated in modern versions; it should now be `gnome-terminal -- command arg1 arg2 ...`

Comment: What makes this _especially_ unfortunate is that modern versions of gnome-terminal have a client/server architecture so when you run `gnome-terminal -e mycommand`, `mycommand` may not even be a subprocess of your shell (or in this case your Python script) at all in the first place; instead, new gnome-terminal versions spin up a systemd user service and instruct _that service_ to spawn a new terminal window.

Comment: Are you sure you _really_ need to use gnome-terminal for this and can't switch to something simpler like xterm?

Answer (score 3):

The `--wait` argument to `gnome-terminal` tells it not to return until its child process exits:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--wait', '--', './script.sh'])
print('Finished')
```